# Get JSON data from Django service

Tags: python, json, ajax, django, request

I'm complety new on django and python. Now I'mtriying to develop a simple service. This is the idea: I send 3 parameters from JS to Django by POST, (from another domain, CORS) in Django, python process the data and return me JSON, that all.

Why have I do that!? , because I need special functions available on pyhon: Statistics.

This is the code that I begin:

**urls.py**

```
   from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from . import controlador #este sisi

    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^get_weibull/', controlador.get_data_weibull)]
```

**controlador.py**

```
  from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def weib(x,n,a):
        return (a / n) * (x / n)**(a - 1) * np.exp(-(x / n)**a)

    def get_data_weibull(self):
        a = 5. # shape
        s= np.random.weibull(a, 1000)
        x = np.arange(1,100.)/50.
        count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(np.random.weibull(5.,1000))
        x = np.arange(1,100.)/50.
        scale = count.max()/weib(x, 1., 5.).max()
        plt.plot(x, weib(x, 1., 5.)*scale)

        ax = plt.gca() 
        line = ax.lines[0]
        return render_to_response(line.get_xydata())
```

This is very simply on codeigniter or laravel. but I dont know how begin this on django.

How Can I do that?

Thanks! 
Rosie

Answer (score 0):

`render_to_response`, which has been superseded/ replaced by by [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) expects to send variables in a dictionary as a "context" to a template. Your `get_data_weibull` view should accept one variable, typically called `request` (`self` is only used as the name of the first argument to an object's function). Then you can construct a dictionary with your line data and return that as a ['JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects).

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


def get_data_weibull(self):
    a = 5. # shape
    s= np.random.weibull(a, 1000)
    x = np.arange(1,100.)/50.
    count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(np.random.weibull(5.,1000))
    x = np.arange(1,100.)/50.
    scale = count.max()/weib(x, 1., 5.).max()
    plt.plot(x, weib(x, 1., 5.)*scale)

    ax = plt.gca() 
    line = ax.lines[0]
    return JsonResponse(line.get_xydata())
```

or if your using an old version of Django, you can return this instead

```
HttpResponse(json.dumps(line.get_xydata()), content_type="application/json")
```